# Print addresses of elements in a vector in C++

Tags: c++

I'm new to programming and I want to know if this is a valid way to print the address of each element in a vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void printAdress( vector<int> & a ) {
    vector<int*> ptr;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        ptr.push_back(&a[i]);
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < ptr.size(); i++) {
        cout << ptr[i] << "\n";
    }
}

int main () {

    vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    printAdress(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Is this error prone? Is there a more efficient way to do this? Am I using unnecessary memory? I'd love some feedback.

Comment: Why create a whole new vector when in your loop you can do `cout << &a[i] << "\n";`?

Comment: `printAddress` should take the vector argument by `const` reference, since it doesn't modify the vector. That doesn't affect correctness, but it's clearer to readers and might catch some errors later on.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, arrays (including the data of a `std::vector` container) are *contiguous* blocks of data elements. Thus, the address of the *i<sup>th</sup>* element of such an array (or vector) is just the address of the array's first element plus the value of `i`. (The addend is *actually* `i * sizeof(element)`, but that size factor is automatically taken into account when performing pointer arithmetic in C++.)

So:

1. As mentioned in the comments, your `printAdress` function has no need to create a new vector (which is lost when the function returns).
2. There is no need to take the address of each element in the vector, once the address of its 'base' (which is available *via* the `data()` member function of the `std::vector` class) is known.

Here's a reasonably efficient example:

```cpp
void printAdress(const std::vector<int>& a)
{
    const int* base = a.data();
    const size_t n = a.size();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) std::cout << (base + i) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I guess this would do the trick too? `for (auto& i : a) cout << &i << "\n";` but might not be as efficient (though fewer keystrokes).

Comment: @DS_London Probably, your code, the OP's original and my suggestion would all boil down to the same thing in assembly. The compiler will likely evaluate `&a[i]` as `&a[0] + i`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative syntax. 'Behind the scenes' this is very likely doing the same as @Adrian Mole's answer (which usefully explains the fundamental concept of C++ pointer arithmetic), but illustrates a few of the other language features which the OP might encounter on their C++ journey:

```
template<typename T>
void printAddress(const std::vector<T>& v)
{
    for (auto& e : v) std::cout << &e << "\n";
}
```

This allows the writing of:

```
using namespace std;

vector<int> a = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
printAddress(a);

vector<double> b = { 1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0 };
printAddress(b);
```

without any additional code in printAddress().

NB: This code doesn't compile for `vector<bool>` which stores the internal data in a different way.